# How to run a test multiple times with different sets of data in cypress?

Tags: javascript, testing, automation, cypress

While automating a website, I have a requirement to run a test case(it block) multiple times with different set of testdata in cypress.

Please consider the below example :

```js
it('example test',  () => {

    //first run
    getOnDefaultForm.typeUserName('Name1');
    getOnDefaultForm.typePassword('Pass1');
    getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();
    
    //second run
    getOnDefaultForm.typeUserName('Name2');
    getOnDefaultForm.typePassword('Pass2');
    getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();
    
    //third run
    getOnDefaultForm.typeUserName('Name3');
    getOnDefaultForm.typePassword('Pass3');
    getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();

});
```

How can I achieve this in Cypress?

Answer (score 13):

It is also possible to put the data in a `json` file in the fixtures folder, and import it at the top of the spec file.

This methodology is still working in Cypress version 12.5.0.

**fixture**

```js
[
  { "name": 'Name1', "password": 'Pass1' },
  { "name": 'Name2', "password": 'Pass2' },
  { "name": 'Name3', "password": 'Pass3' }
]
```

**test**

```js
const testData = require('../fixtures/test-data.json')

testData.forEach((credentials) => {
  it('example test for ' + credentials.name, () => {
    getOnDefaultForm.typeUserName(credentials.name);
    getOnDefaultForm.typePassword(credentials.password);
    getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();
  })
})
```

Answer (score 9):

I think you need to have a look as this repo: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__dynamic-tests Or just search this site, this is not the first time someone has asked this very question.

In general, you can wrap your `it` in a loop. In practice, it'd look e.g. like this:

```js
const testData = [
    {
        name: 'Name1',
        password: 'Pass1'
    },
    {
        name: 'Name2',
        password: 'Pass2'
    },
    {
        name: 'Name3',
        password: 'Pass3'
    }
]

testData.forEach((credentials) => {
    it('example test', () => {
        getOnDefaultForm.typeUserName(credentials.name);
        getOnDefaultForm.typePassword(credentials.password);
        getOnDefaultForm.clickSubmit();
    })
});
```

Comment: Could someone comment on this: will the test for "Name3" execute if the test for "Name2" fails?  Was just getting ready to try this and hoping that one failure doesn't block remaining tests in forEach

Comment: whats the harm in wrapping the describe block?

Comment: @chrismead the order here doesn't block them. It's the same as if normally writing multiple separate it() in one file - they run one after another independent of each other's failures/successes.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old but I was looking for the same thing and I couldn't find the good option for me. I needed to read the CSV file and use the same test case with different set of data (actually, what DDT is about, real parametrization). I found the best answer here: https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/fundamentals__dynamic-tests-from-csv

So what you need to do is:

1. Add the setup function to the cypress.config.js -> e2e. This example puts the parsed CSV array to the env.usersList:

```
    // imports
    const fs = require('fs')
    const path = require('path')
    const neatCSV = require('neat-csv')
    
    // the func itself
    async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      const filename = path.join(__dirname, 'cypress/fixtures/contact.csv')
      const text = fs.readFileSync(filename, 'utf8')
      const csv = await neatCSV(text)
      config.env.usersList = csv
      return config
    }
```

2. Then you can access it in any test case using the Cypress.env:

```
describe('Data-driven testing from CSV file', () => {
    const csvUsers = Cypress.env('usersList')

    csvUsers.forEach(user => {
        it(`Fill input fields from the CSV file - user "${user.name}"`, () => {
            cy.visit('https://your-app/')

            cy.get('#some-id1').type(user.name)
            cy.get('#some-id2').type(user.email)

        })
    })
})
```